# Replace Multiple columns at once with fillna()

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataFrame with two column of Null values

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ddd = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3],'b' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'c' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan] })
```

I want to replace column b and c with column a values. I am doing this

```
ddd[['b','c']]= ddd.fillna(ddd.a)
```

I get error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

When i do this the values still remain as NAN

```
ddd.iloc[:,1:] = ddd.fillna(ddd.a)
```

It only works if i do individually like this

```
ddd.b = ddd.fillna(ddd.a)
ddd.c = ddd.fillna(ddd.a)
```

My Expected output is

```
   a    b    c
0  1  1.0  1.0
1  2  2.0  2.0
2  3  3.0  3.0
```

Anyway to make in work in single line I have more than 500 columns in my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate on all the column BUT the first one:

```
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    ddd[column]= ddd['a']
```

Comment: getting ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: I have edited the answer. I was hoping for a neater solution, but the above works

Comment: yes this works but I have 500 columns, My question was the same how to do this in one line rather than 500 lines.